# RESTful URL: where should I put locale? example.com/en/page vs example.com/page?locale=en

Tags: url, rest, path, locale

I'm deciding how to organize URL and put locale into it. I have two choices:

1. example.com/en/page
2. example.com/page?locale=en -- Google way
3. <strike>en.example.com/page</strike> -- isn't good because I'm using subdomains

From one side `example.com/en/page` looks better and more compact than `example.com/page?locale=en`.
From other side we have two URLs `example.com/en/page` and `example.com/ru/page` for one resource with two representations.
Of course in case `example.com/page?locale=en` we have two URLs for one resource too, but it is slightly more RESTful on my taste.

What's the best practice? What are you using and why?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Localization is part of Content-Negotiation in Restful API.

So my preferred way I would do it through headers. HTTP offers standard way of defining wanted language. Have a look at [Accept-Language](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html) header.

Comment: Yes. I know about Accept-Language. But in Russia, for example, a lot of people use English locale but prefer content in Russian. So if I will use only Accept-Language they will have no chance to change language of content (except of course change locale of browser). Most common solution is language switcher in site layout. So I trying to understand what is is the best way to organizing such switcher.

Comment: I see, so your api-client's are browsers (e.g. through AJAX calls)? Then I would go for your proposed url parameter way (like ?lang=en), because the offer you 'optional' semantics (with fallback to Accept-Language header).

Comment: Browsers and external services. Thanks for your opinion, I'm thinking in the same way.

Comment: I don't see the problem with using `Accept-Language`. Yes, when your *browser* sends the HTTP request for a page (likely just your SPA index), it will send the value set in the browser's settings. But for all your requests to the API, using *Ajax*, surely you can specify any value you'd like for this header - any decent framework will allow you to configure this automatically. So you can still let the user pick a locale from a dropdown list, for instance, and always send that along with every consecutive request.

Answer (score 30):

From https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales:

> The HTTP Accept-Language header was originally only intended to specify the user's language. However, since many applications need to know the locale of the user, common practice has used Accept-Language to determine this information. **It is not a good idea to use the HTTP Accept-Language header alone to determine the locale of the user**. If you use Accept-Language exclusively, you may handcuff the user into a set of choices not to his liking.

My preference:

- Request

  - use a query parameter
  - fall-back to `Accept-Language` header if query parameter is not 
    specified
  - fall-back to **documented** default Locale if `Accept-Language` header is not defined
- Response

  - Set `Content-Language`
  - Set locale in response payload, like `<some-root-tag xml:lang="en-US">` (see http://www.opentag.com/xfaq_lang.htm)