# Multi-lingual REST resources - URL naming suggestions

Tags: rest, restful-url

Is there a REST best practice for GETting resources in different languages. Currently, we have

```
www.mysite.com/books?locale=en
```

I know we can use the accept-language header but is it better for us to do

```
www.mysite.com/books/en or www.mysite.com/books.en
```

or does it not matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892502/restful-url-where-should-i-put-locale-example-com-en-page-vs-example-com-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think best way would be to implement this following way:

1. HTTP's Accept-Language header
2. Language prefix in URI such as /en/books/...

In other words you can accept language from both sources. Implementation will be following:

1. Check if Accept-Language header is provided and keep this in the variable;
2. If request URI starts with **/en, /fr** or other known language codes(that are supported by your system) Overwrite language variable with this new value, strip it from URI i.e. if URI is **/en/books** you will end up with **/books**.
3. If there is no language provided, keep default language in variable for example "en"

With this approach you can make sure that a) path routing will be language agnostic and your system will work uniformly with paths; b) language handling/negotiation will be completely separated from your scripts. You can use language information in your scripts without even knowing what was the source and how it was requested.

Answer (score 21):

If you're trying to have your server return different translations or localized versions of the same books (in other words, the same resource from a RESTful perspective), then use [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) because the resource is the same but the representation is different based on the client's needs.

However if you're trying to return *completely different books* based on the client's locale (say, returning books written in French if you know that the user is in France) then the URIs should be different since different resources would be returned. At this point, you're talking more about a query request more than anything else. For what it's worth, the `/books/en` approach sounds reasonable. Another approach would be to add the locale or language as a resource parameter to GET as `/books?lang=en`.

Comment: Indeed - it's truly RESTful way! You're absolutely right! But it's easier to test rest interface in browser or using curl when language argument in path :) So my suggestion is detecting language on server checking headers and url arguments both.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with comment of  [manuel-aldana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236370/manuel-aldana) in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7893637/52277) to the question [RESTful URL: where should I put locale? example.com/en/page vs example.com/page?locale=en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892502/restful-url-where-should-i-put-locale-example-com-en-page-vs-example-com-page)

Check for parameter (e.g. locale=en ) first to allow client explicitely specify language with fallback to [Accept-Language](http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Headers/Accept-Language)

Comment: Shouldn't this just be a comment instead of an awnser.