# localisation in RESTful services

Tags: web-services, rest, localization, content-negotiation

I have a RESTful service that returns an enum.

I was pondering whether to return integers or strings for an enum value, when it occurred to me that returning a string would depend on the locale of the client.

So how should you handle localisation in REST?  Is locale part of conneg?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Localisation *is* part of content negotiation, and language preferences are specified using the `Accept-Language` header ([RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4)).

The RFC is quite strict about what the service is allowed to return here — for instance, if no header is sent, then you may choose any language, but if a header is included, then you may only return one of the requested languages, and are not allowed to fall back to a different language.

In other words, if a resource is only available in English, then a resource requested with `Accept-Language: de` should return `406 Unacceptable` rather than default to presenting the English version.

Other alternatives that don't use the specification but do allow for fallback options are discussed in a couple of other questions ([8204816](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204816/multi-lingual-rest-resources-url-naming-suggestions), [7892502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892502/restful-url-where-should-i-put-locale-example-com-en-page-vs-example-com-page)).

Comment: As of RFC7231, [this is no longer the case](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.5). Indeed, treating the response as if it was not subject to content negotiation (and returning English by default) is preferred over sending a 406, as not doing so "can prevent users from accessing content that they might be able to use".