# How to use HATEOAS with localization

Tags: rest, multilingual, hateoas

For a client to get a resource in a specific language over HTTP I see the following technical implementations for the API:

1. Query Parameter
2. `Accept-Language` Header
3. URI path segment (e.g. /en/, /de/)
4. `Accept Header` and various representation types
5. Cookie
6. User preferences stored on the server

The stackoverflow post [Multi-lingual REST resources - URL naming suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204816/multi-lingual-rest-resources-url-naming-suggestions/8206552#8206552) discusses some of the above options.

If the translations are considered a representations of the resource and therefore the recommended `Accept-Language` header is used I wonder how can this work with HATEOAS?

I can't add the header to the URI. My understanding is that the client should not construct URIs when HATEOAS is used. But this means that there is no option to use header information, like `Accept-Language` or `Accept Header`. Is there something I miss or didn't understand correctly?

I wanted to use only the `Accept-Language` header, but I only can see two option to support HATEOAS in the JSON response to list the links to the available languages: query parameter and URI path segment.
E.g.

```
{
  "className": "Swing Dancing",
  "description": "Learn to dance Lindy Hop for beginners.",
  language": "en",
  "_links": {
    "lang-de": "/classes/5/?lang=de",
    "lang-fr": "/classes/5/fr"
  }
}
```

Our application supports multi-language for each supported field of a resource. E.g a class can have a title stored only in one language (e.g. English) and the description in multiple languages. It solely depends on the translations the users of the system have entered. The best match for each field according to the user request is returned. E.g. prefered languages in order "FR, DE, EN", Then the result would look like this:

```
{
  "className": {
    "value": "Swing Dancing",
    "language": "en"
  }
  "description": {
    "value": "Lerne Lindy Hop für Anfänger.",
    "language": "de"
  }
}
```

Since the class name in the example is only stored in English it is returned in English even when English is not a preference of the user.

My proposed implementation is to support the following options in this order:

1. Query Parameter
2. `Accept-Language` Header
3. User preferences stored on the server
4. Application default

If a query parameter is provided it is used first. This allowes fetching a specific language e.g. for staff to edit the content. Supporting the query parameter also allows to use HATEOAS in the response.

Next the `Accept-Language` is checked. If both contain no information the user preferences are loaded. If the user have no preferences the application default is used.

REST calls should be stateless. I'm unsure about the user preferences. They are not session information and only a constant preference that is fetched using the passed userId. Would that still conform to the REST specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't add the header to the URI. My understanding is that the client should not construct URIs when HATEOAS is used. But this means that there is no option to use header information, like Accept-Language or Accept Header. Is there something I miss or didn't understand correctly?

Values for the Accept-Language field, like values for the Accept field, would normally be part of the configuration of the user agent, rather than something we attempt to control via the representations of the resources.  See [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-accept-language)

> Since intelligibility is highly dependent on the individual user, user agents need to allow user control over the linguistic preference (either through configuration of the user agent itself or by defaulting to a user controllable system setting). A user agent that does not provide such control to the user MUST NOT send an Accept-Language header field.

---

Roy Fielding, [writing in 2006](https://web.archive.org/web/20150610025808/https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/5857):

> The sites that I produce *always* separate languages into separate URI trees. Day Software's Communiqué product specializes in multilingual sites and defaults to separate trees.

In his example

```
http://www.day.com/
```

redirects to the appropriate index...

```
http://www.day.com/site/en/index.html
http://www.day.com/site/de/index.html
```

Of course, you might reasonably prefer reactive negotiation to proactive negotiation.  See [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-content-negotiation).

---

The machines don't care if you use path segments or the query part to distinguish a resource that expresses its representations in one language from another.

The usual constraints do apply: query parameters are more convenient for HTML forms, path parameters are more convenient when you want to leverage relative resolution.  If you care to put in the extra work, it's *fine* to have a supported spelling redirect to the preferred spelling.

---

If we want to communicate to the client the language of the resulting representation of a resource, the most straight forward standardized solution is probably an [RFC 8288](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288.html#section-3.4.1) hreflang parameter paired with an [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646#section-2) Language Tag.

(A quick review of the [registered link relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) offers [alternate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-alternate) as a possible candidate for the relation itself.  Probably reasonable, but I'm not confident that it is necessarily "best".)

---

> To understand the header use better I have a follow up question: The users preferred languages are send via the header. If the user wants to see a resource in a specific language that has not the highest priority or is not in the list of preferences should the client app send a different Accept-Language header for that request or should a query parameter/uri path be used instead?

If you are trying to keep things simple for yourself: design your resource model with separate resources for each language; include in the representation of each resource links to the parallel resources in the other languages.

And yes, if your DE representation of the information is a resource with mostly DE representation but an EN title, that's *fine* (from the perspective of HTTP, which really only cares about the [moving-documents-around-the-network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) bit).

In the advanced version, extend the simple resource model with additional resources that have multiple representations, with links all around.

Comment: Thank for the great and valuable information. Is there any RFC or recommendation on how to deal with multiple languages in one response? As I wrote, our resources may not be translated completely. Some fields may be translated and others not. Using the preferences in the `accept-language` header we return a best match. For editing purposes of a concrete language we will now use a query parameter or path segment for access. Not translated fields will be returned empty.

Comment: I'm not sure what "deal with multiple languages in one response" is supposed to mean?

Comment: If you look at my example above you can see that the title of the class resource is in a different language then the description. This is very common in our business. Class titles may be translated, but the description might be not.

Comment: To understand the header use better I have a follow up question: The users preferred languages are send via the header. If the user wants to see a resource in a specific language that has not the highest priority or is not in the list of preferences should the client app send a different `Accept-Language` header for that request or should a query parameter/uri path be used instead? The client is a programmed front end app that sends the request and controlls it.

Comment: I tried extending the answer to address this concern; let me know if it helps.