# REST API request with language and region

Tags: java, rest, api, http, http-accept-language

I'm developing a REST API and I need to implement a method which needs language and country to produce result in the correct format since the result contains numbers and dates.

I was using the HTTP `Accept-Language` header to get the language. The specs define the header as a language specifier, but now I'm not sure if it is correct to use this header for getting the country. For example, I want to allow a result in Spanish language but with numbers in English format (with commas instead of dots).

Is `es-US` an accepted value for the `Accept-Language` header?

I was thinking that I could develop a new custom header like `X-Country` for my REST API.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by that ?(but with numbers in english format (with commas instead of dots)

Comment: Format number depends on the region. For example, spanish representation 4.294.967.295,000  against US-English 4,294,967,295.00  (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

Comment: Well, I should have said "with commas instead of period"

Comment: A feedback for my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50987031/1426227) is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are good documents out there on how to [localize your APIs](http://apiux.com/2013/04/25/how-to-localize-your-api/).  There is even a [stack overflow response about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892502/restful-url-where-should-i-put-locale-example-com-en-page-vs-example-com-page).

Mostly it revolves around [content negotiation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.10) and the "Accept-Language" header.  If you need to have currency managed separately, the general consensus seems to keep in in the payload rather then in headers, but if you are going to do headers I would do  `X-Accept-Currency` (behaving akin to the other HTTP Accept headers, but with ISO 4217 currency codes) on the request, and `X-Content-Currency` on the response.

UPDATE:
Things have changed - if you intend to submit your header for standardization, you should not prefix it with X.

Answer (score 3):

> I was thinking that I could develop a new custom header like `X-Country` for my REST API.

I would avoid custom headers if one of the standard HTTP headers suit your needs.

> Is `es-US` an accepted value for `Accept-Language` header?

Yes, `es-US` (Spanish / United States) is a *valid* locale <sup>(see the notes below)</sup> and it's a suitable value for the [`Accept-Language`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5) header:

> [**5.3.5.  Accept-Language**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5)
>
> The `Accept-Language` header field can be used by user agents to
> indicate the set of natural languages that are preferred in the
> response.  Language tags are defined in [Section 3.1.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.3.1). [...]

The relevant parts of the [section 3.1.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.3.1) are quoted below:

> [**3.1.3.1.  Language Tags**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.3.1)
>
> A language tag, as defined in [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646), identifies a natural
> language spoken, written, or otherwise conveyed by human beings for
> communication of information to other human beings.  Computer
> languages are explicitly excluded. [...]
>
> A language tag is a sequence of one or more case-insensitive subtags,
> each separated by a hyphen character (`-`, `%x2D`).  In most cases, a
> language tag consists of a primary language subtag that identifies a
> broad family of related languages (e.g., `en` = English), which is
> optionally followed by a series of subtags that refine or narrow that
> language's range (e.g., `en-CA` = the variety of English as
> communicated in Canada).  Whitespace is not allowed within a language
> tag.  Example tags include:
>
> ```
> fr, en-US, es-419, az-Arab, x-pig-latin, man-Nkoo-GN
> ```
>
> See [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646) for further information.

---

<sup>**Note 1:** The combinations of language and territory codes that can be considered *valid* (in the sense that a given population of a given territory is able to read and write a given language, and is comfortable enough to use it with computers) can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/territory_language_information.html).</sup>

<sup>**Note 2:** Not sure which programming language you are using, but [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html)'s the list of locales available in Java.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts? Thanks.

My recommendation would be to start from having a resource for each (language, country) that you support, then worry about whether you want to have a single resource that does [content negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4).

A simple pattern for a resource that uses content negotiation would be to use the [Content-Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.2) header to point back to the specific resource for the negotiated language/country pair.

See also [Tom Christie's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/170409/199871) from 2012, especially the link to [Fielding's comment in 2006](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/5857)